# High CPU temperature of new Clevo w350ST Laptop

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

I just recently bought a new Clevo W350ST laptop. While everything has been working extremely fine in it, its the CPU temperatures on the laptop I am worried about.

The Tj Max. for my processor (i7 4700MQ) is given as 100 degrees C.

When I play heavy graphic games like battlefield 4, my CPU temperature levels shoot up to the 93-99 degree C region. Considering that the maximum temperature is 100 degrees, this makes me extremely worried.

At the same time though, the GPU temperature is normal. Maximum GPU temperature for this model is said to be around 70-05 degrees, which is very cool (I am told I should worry if it goes around 90 for gpu)

Another thing to note is that, none of the heavy games that I play function improperly. They work perfectly fine, eventhough the cpu temperature readings show such high temperatures.

I am attaching a screenshot for reference.

My questions are:

1. **Is this temperature normal?** Since the laptop and games work perfectly fine under these high maximum cpu temperatures?
2. Say if it's normal, **is there any long term harm to the processor or any other internals** because of this?

I just got this laptop 2 days ago and it claims to have excellent temperature management. So I am extremely worried about this.

Any help, advice, is much appreciated.

#### Screenshot illustrating game and CPU temperature

[image: Screenshot of Battlefield 4 and temperatures showing around 95 degrees celsius for each core.]

Comment: At an average, the idle temps are between 47-52 degrees. I am using windows 8.1 OS.

Comment: My immediate thought is that your laptop sadly isn't that good at expelling heat as it is meant to. The reasons to this could be fan ports that are blocked during use, or other parts - perhaps a fan that isn't working?

Comment: Yeah, those idle temps are low enough that the actual heatsink assembly must be attached correctly, so I'd guess it's a fan maybe?  I do doubt it's supposed to be THAT hot.

Comment: Thats what confuses me more. Because this is a new piece, I am sure the fan is working perfectly well. I can listen to it working and also expelling heat. So those areas are fine.

Comment: Besides, if the fan was the issue, wouldn't the gpu be affected too? But the gpu temperatures are fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. first normally processor can handle about 80 degrees C
   but if you're running the game on full resolution you might need extra cooler from outside (fan cooler)
2. it's also have effect for another hardware such as HDD, RAM, motherboard itself
   so be wise